Jacobian change of basis for integration
I just wanted to see if anyone could verify my work.
I'm trying to integrate the function $f(x,y) = xy$ over the circle of center $(1, 2)$ and radius $2$. The conversion I am using is:
$x = r\cos\theta + 1$
$y = r\sin\theta + 2$
And the determinant of the Jacobian comes out to just $r$.
Therefore I am setting the integral up as follows:
$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^2 (r\cos\theta + 1)(r\sin\theta + 2)rdrd\theta$ as I am assuming my new $r, \theta$ measure the angle/radius from the center (1, 2). Does that look correct, or have I made a mistake somewhere?

What happened to $f(x,y)$? And you forgot the backslash in \sin and \cos. :-) But the coordinate transformation looks fine.

Apologies, $f(x,y) = xy$ lol. Fixed now
